# Awk trouble passing in shell variables

Tags: shell, awk

This question has been asked on here; however I followed the examples and my script still does not work. I am passing in a filename to awk from shell script. The problem is, `var` is not expanded into the filename.

Here is a line:

```
plot=`awk -v var="$state_file" FNR==1{print} var`
```

awk just complains that it cannot open the file `var`.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It's completely unclear from your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not put quotes around the *script* portion, which is necessary for the shell to pass it to awk as a single argument.  It should be something like this:

```
plot=$(awk -v var="$state_file" 'FNR==1{print} var')
```

(using single quotes, for example).  Because of the missing quotes, awk sees that as two arguments (and according to its [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk), the second is assumed to be a file):

```
FNR==1{print}
var
```

From the OP's comment, perhaps `$state_file` is the name of a file which should be processed by awk.  Normally that would be something like this:

```
plot=$(awk 'FNR==1{print}' < "$state_file")
```

or

```
plot=$(awk 'FNR==1{print}' "$state_file")
```

Comment: Hi, this gets stuck on the statement. I've verified that the state_file exists, and used sh -x option to see.

Comment: As I read it, your example is incomplete, since awk expects to read stream of data - but I see none.  However, the question appeared to focus on (a) problem passing in a shell variable, and (b) the unexplained message about a file named var.  Normally I would see a file piped to awk rather than given as a variable.

Comment: I think tha very last thing is what the OP is looking for but you should make it clear that it should be written as `plot=$(awk 'FNR==1{print}' "$state_file")`, i.e. with the quoted shell variable and without the deprecated backticks.